# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-support-library, android-multidex, dexoptions

I have recently updated android studio but there are problems in build.gradle file. How can I resolve this issue? Adding debug{} and staging{} to gradle (4.8) and using matchingFallbacks not worked. Thank you. regards.

```
 Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not 
 resolve com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2.
 Open File
 Show Details

 Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': 
 Could not resolve com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.2.
 Open File
 Show Details

 Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not 
 resolve com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2.
 Open File
 Show Details
```

gradle:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xx.yyyy"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

}
productFlavors {
}
dexOptions{
    //incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "12g"
}

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
implementation project(':multidex-1.0.2')
implementation project(':multidex-instrumentation-1.0.2')
}
```